Difference between maven scope compile and provided but in different run time environment and jar packaging
I referred to this question: Difference between maven scope compile and provided for JAR packaging
The answer to the above question says that when packaging is jar, difference between these scopes are:

provided dependencies are not transitive when provided
the dependencies are added to the class path by maven when scope is compile

the answer to the above questions do not say anything about the runtime env being different from the compilation and packaging environment.
In my case jar packaging is used and scope of some of the dependencies is set to provided and the rest are set to the default. Environment where I compile and package my jar(my personal laptop) is different from my runtime environment(server). Given the above context, can I conclude the only difference between provided and compile scopes is:

provided dependencies aren't transitive

So can I use the either of the scopes interchangeably?

"Given above context". You didn't provide much context. Maybe you can share a concrete example of what your environments look like. But generally speaking, no you should not use them interchangeably, the post you linked explain this. If some dependencies are provided by your runtime environment, set their scope to provided, otherwise don't.

Since my packaging is jar and runtime environment is separate, for dependencies of provided and compile, the dependencies are expected to be present in the class path right?

This question is similar to: Difference between maven scope compile and provided for JAR packaging. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does Maven documentation answer your question? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope.

Also note that there are several answers in the original question in that link. Have you reviewed all of them?

@tru So how do you provide the dependencies to your program? Do you use a fat JAR? Or do you start the program with an explicit classpath?

I think the simple guideline is: if you aren’t running your program in some kind of app server or other container environment, there’s no need to use provided scope
